# Sending ROS messages through a cv2 python script

Tags: python, ros, opencv, robotics, markers

I am trying to implement a robotic solution, where the user will click on a point through a camera feed of an area and the mobile 4 wheel robot will path its way to that location.
I have created the part of translating video pixel coordinates to ground coordinates through the use of the homograph transformation and would like to implement the part of sending the ground coordinates to RViz.
The part of calculating the ground coordinates is shown bellow:

```
global h
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX #Loading neccessary fonts

with open("save.h", "rb") as f:
    h = load(f)


print "Homographic matrix loaded successfully."

def draw_circle2(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global h,mouseX,mouseY, num_of_points, complete,np_coord_on_screen,np_coord_on_ground, myImage, emptyFrame, coord_on_screen, coord_on_ground

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:

        a = np.array([[x, y]], dtype='float32')
        a = np.array([a])
        pointOut = cv2.perspectiveTransform(a, h) #Calculation of new point location

        loc_pointOut = tuple(pointOut)

        pointOut=(loc_pointOut[0][0][0],loc_pointOut[0][0][1]) #Point on ground

        print "Current Location: "+str(pointOut)
        cv2.imshow('Video',emptyFrame) #Showing emptyFrame
        cv2.circle(myImage,(x,y),4,(255,0,0),-1) #Draw a circle on myImage
        cv2.putText(myImage,(str((round(pointOut[0],2)))+","+str(round(pointOut[1],2))), (x-5,y-15),font, 0.4,(0,255,0)) #Draw the text
        cv2.imshow('Video',myImage) #Showing resulting myImage

        myImage = emptyFrame.copy()



# Initial code 
# Showing first frame on screen
raw_input("Press any key...")
clear_all()
cv2.namedWindow('Video') #Naming the window to use.
cv2.setMouseCallback('Video',draw_circle2) #Set mouse callBack function.
ret, frame = cap.read() #Get image from camera
if (ret): #If frame has image, show the image on screen
    global myImage, emptyFrame
    myImage = frame.copy()
    emptyFrame = frame.copy()
    cv2.imshow('Video',myImage) # Show the image on screen



while True:  # making a loop

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('c')):
        #Deleting points from image

        cv2.imshow('Video',emptyFrame) #Show the image again, deleting all graphical overlays like text and shapes
        coord_on_screen = []        #Resetting coordinate lists
        coord_on_ground=[]          #Resetting coordinate lists
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s')):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        init()


# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So, pointOut is the point on the ground (example: (2,4) m)
I need some directions on how to implement the creation of a node and the transmission of the pointOut Marker message to a ROS topic in my code.

My configuration is ROS Kinetic Kame, Python 2.7

Comment: You can use class functions to make your code cleaner. If I am not mistaken you can start creating a publishing node http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29. Simply add your current code into a sub function that calls publish with the values you want on your custom message etc.

Comment: Yes, I know about my code. I am trying to get to a point and then will clean it up because it started bad. I have already tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I'll try it again and post some code and the errors it produced..

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it turns out it is correct.
It seems it was very simple after all. For some reason though, the first time I tried I got several errors making me believe it couldn't be achieved in such a simple manner.

Comment: Glad the comment helped. :D